# Yii : Save data to new table

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii and have a basic doubt.
I am working on an app where I have to store data submitted in one form into a new table.

As I know one table=one model
should I create a new model for the new table using gii?

Can't I just use the following code without creating the model in gii?

```
$modelA = new table_name;
$modelA->attributes = $_POST['table_name'];
$modelA->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to create model, because:

```
$modelA = new ModelClassName();
```

and not table name. You still may use *relations* for other tables, so you can have only one model:

```
$modelA->tableNameB->attributes = $_POST['attributes4B'];
```

Comment: Okie! But its giving me an error as ModelClassName.tableNameB is not defined

Comment: @user3496974 Have you set relations in 'class ModelClassName{}'? And it's not via dot, it's via arrow.